# Kernel of alternating bilinear form A - A^T

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

Let $A$ be a matrix over a field of characteristic different than two. For convenienve, let's suppose $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$.

Let $A$ be strictly upper triangular and $B = A - A^T$ the corresponding skew-symmetric matrix. Consider the following two bilinear forms:
$$\alpha_A : \mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}: (v,w) \mapsto v^TAw$$
and
$$ \alpha_B : \mathbb{C}^n\times\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}: (v,w) \mapsto v^TBw.$$

Is the following statement correct?

$$\ker \alpha_B \subset \ker\alpha_A,$$
where $\ker\alpha = (\mathbb{C}^n)^\perp = \{ v\in \mathbb{C}^n \mid \forall w\in \mathbb{C}^n : \alpha(v,w) = 0 \}$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: I hope it is true. I've been thinking about reduction to its diagonal form (over C) for B and then applying the same procedure to A, but I don't immediately see why this would preserve the bottom zeros.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is not true. Let
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 &1\\
0 & 0 &1
\\ 0 &0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$ Then
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 &1\\
-1 & 0 &1
\\-1 &-1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
The condition $v^TCw=0$ for any $w$ is equivalent to $C^Tv=0.$ Let $v=(1,-1,1).$ Then $B^Tv=-Bv=0,$ but $A^Tv\neq 0.$